# Reducing Current?

Tags: batteries, current, amperage

Having a problem with my EV a converted Fiat 500. 
The conversion is made with part from companies that dont exist any more, 
so it is hard to get information about them.
The car have two batterybanks 83Ah, 43Ah.
When i drive the car the smaller bank is draining much faster then the bigger.  A reason for that could be that the batteries in the smaller bank is new and has lower internal resistance.
I also gets a warning "Discharge Over Current" from the smaller pack.
So when the smaller pack is empty it signaling to turn off the car.
At that moment the bigger pack has SOC 70% (State Of Charge).
My theory is that if I could reduce to current in the smaller pack I could empty the both packs in the same time.
Are there a way to reduce the current to 70 amp in a 100V application?

Comment: This is almost certainly beyond the scope of internet Q&A. I strongly recommend you hire a professional to work with you on this directly. Please do not risk hurting yourself or others if you aren't sure what you are doing!

Comment: Current sharing is not a trivial task. But limiting your acceleration ought to be easy.  In series, the weakest cell degrades the fastest. In parallel, the strongest cell does the most work.  ( strong = low ESR)